# How do i hide child <ul>'s when scrolled to a certain id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I hide my child ul's when they're not supposed to be visible i.e when someone have scrolled to another section? Could you listen for a specific 'frame'/position to show the different sub menus, or perhaps see which section that has the active class and then take that ones `.attr('id')` and show the corresponding one in the `nav`?

I hope someone here could contribute with a solution that has good browser support (if that could be an issue).

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/j4Y2h/17/)

Markup:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#1">First</a>
         <ul id="sub-menu1">
             <li>Item 1</li>
             <li>Item 2</li>
         </ul> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="#2">Second</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#3">Third</a>
        <ul id="sub-menu3">
             <li>Item 1</li>
             <li>Item 2</li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#4">Fourth</a>
        <ul id="sub-menu4">
             <li>Item 1</li>
             <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#5">Fifth</a>
          <ul id="sub-menu5">
             <li>Item 1</li>
             <li>Item 2</li>
         </ul> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="sections">
  <section id="1"><h1>First</h1></section>
  <section id="2"><h1>Second</h1></section>
  <section id="3"><h1>Third</h1></section>
  <section id="4"><h1>Fourth</h1></section>
  <section id="5"><h1>Fifth</h1></section>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
var sections = $('section')
, nav = $('nav')
, nav_height = nav.outerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();

    sections.each(function() {
        var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
            bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();

        if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
            nav.find('a').removeClass('active');
            sections.removeClass('active');

            $(this).addClass('active');
            var link = nav.find('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]');
            link.addClass('active');

            // Calling this function just to see if there is a sub menu to show
            checkSubmenu(link);
        }
    });
});

// Want to check if there is a Submenu - if, then show it.
// But it should also hide a sub-menu not corresponding to the correct section
// which this solutions does not support
function checkSubmenu(el) {
    if(el.next('ul').length) {
        el.next('ul').slideDown();
    } else {
        $('nav > ul > li > ul').slideUp();
    }
}

nav.find('a').on('click', function () {
    var $el = $(this)
    , id = $el.attr('href');

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(id).offset().top - nav_height
    }, 500);

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a somewhat other approach: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4Y2h/18/)**

This doesn't loop all sections, but rather filters the sections on the 'current' section (with filter).
Then it finds the submenu, if any, based on the section number and nav id, much in the same way as was done in the original code.
Every active class, *not* in that collection, is hidden (slideUp), at the same time removing the active class.
Finally, if not already active, the appropriate submenu is shown.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();

    //find visible section
    var sect = sections.filter(function(){
        var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
            bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();
        return cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom;
    });

    //find submenu 
    var submenu = nav.find('a[href="#'+sect.attr('id')+'"]').next('ul');        
    //hide previously shown, not in the current selection
    $('.active').not(submenu).slideUp().removeClass('active');   
    //if not already active, show
    submenu.not('.active').addClass('active').slideDown();

});
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It does what i asked for, thank you. The only thing though is that if you are on the first List item and clicks on the fifth, then it will show all of the other sub-menus on the way to the fifth, which is unfortunately nothing i would like to have. Any easy fix for this? @Me.Name

Comment: The easiest fix (while keeping the animation), would be to suspend the scroll function while animating, and using the complete of the animate function to reset the flag. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/j4Y2h/20/

Comment: Or a slightly smoother version, that hides the current menu when scrolling begins: http://jsfiddle.net/j4Y2h/22/

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort. Much better, but too bad that it sometimes flashes, if you jump from 1st to 4th, you will see the 3rd sub menu for a split second... :/